# Python singly linked list - removing an element

Tags: python, data-structures

for some reason my remove_element method does not delete ALL nodes containing an element. Why?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element
        self.next = None

class SLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # add a node to front
    def add_front(self, element):
        new_node = Node(element)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

    # removes from the head
    def remove(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print "Error: the list is empty."
        else:
            self.head = self.head.next

    # removes all nodes which hold a given element
    def remove_element(self, element):
        previous = None
        cursor = self.head

        while cursor != None:
            if cursor.element == element:
                if cursor == self.head:
                    self.remove()
                else:
                    previous.next = cursor.next

            previous = cursor
            cursor = cursor.next

    # traverses the list and prints out its elements
    def print_list(self):
        cursor = self.head
        while (cursor != None):
            print(cursor.element)
            cursor = cursor.next

# Main
SLL = SLL()
SLL.add_front(21)
SLL.add_front(21)
SLL.add_front(1)
SLL.add_front(1)
SLL.add_front(1)
SLL.add_front(2)
SLL.add_front(3)
SLL.add_front(5)
SLL.add_front(8)
SLL.add_front(13)
SLL.add_front(21)
SLL.print_list()
print
SLL.remove_element(1)
SLL.print_list()
print
```

Output:

```
bash-3.2$ python SLL.py 
21
13
8
5
3
2
1
1
1
21
21

21
13
8
5
3
2
1 <--- What is this guy doing here?
21
21
```

Comment: Why are you implementing a linked list in Python? Unless it's a homework assignment there's no good reason to do this. Also, PEP8 suggests to use `is` and `is not` when comparing to `None`.

Comment: Just revising data structures and teaching myself python

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks, will have to read the whole style suggestions document.

Comment: As a bonus task once everything is working it'd be a nice idea to add add some [`__*__` methods](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html) like `__iter__` and `__contains__` so you can use the common operators/statements (`if foo in bar`, `for foo in bar`, etc.) on your structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to move the `previous` variable reference when you're removing an element:

```
while cursor != None:
    if cursor.element == element:
        if cursor == self.head:
            self.remove()
        else:
            previous.next = cursor.next                
    else:
        previous = cursor

    cursor = cursor.next
```

Otherwise, every time you remove an element, you skip the next element by reassigning `previous` and `cursor` variables.

Comment: `cursor` still needs to be changed.

Comment: Infinite loop :) But thanks, i get the idea - i just need to adjust the cursor

Comment: @interjay, yes, there was an indentation issue also. thanks for pointing out the mistake!